# Table and graphic frame

Tags: tables, graphics

Is there any LaTeX package that can produce tables and figures like the example in the folowing image by default?

[image: wanted]

EDIT:

I used `tcolorbox` but I did not get the result needed as I'm not familiar with its options.
here is my code (I found it [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122848/tikz-the-pretty-boxes-to-frame-the-theorems-lemma-proposition-etc))

```
\newtcolorbox{theorem}[1][]{
breakable,
enhanced,
colback=white,
colframe=black,
top=\baselineskip,
enlarge top by=\topsep,
overlay unbroken and first={
  \node[xshift=100pt,thick,draw=black,fill=white,anchor=west] at (frame.north west) %
  {\refstepcounter{theorem}\strut{\bfseries\theoname~\thetheorem}\if#1\@empty\relax\relax\else~: #1\fi};
  }
}
```

and this is the result
[image]

How can I customise it in order to be similar to the above one?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I think you're looking for [`pgfplots`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) package.

Comment: Thak you for your quick response, but I'm not looking for producing a graph, I'm just looking for the formatting above

Comment: 'By default' is a bit of a broad term here: as already mentioned, there are packages such as `pgfplots` that can make plots, but you will have to make changes to get a good reproduction of the example.

Comment: @user42987: I've likely misunderstood, but after reading: "Is there any package in Latex that can produce table and _figure_ [..]", I think is pretty normal to suggest a package that can draw the figure. Could you be more specific then?

Comment: May be it's my fault, I'm not a native English speaker.
The graphics (charts for example) are produced using R and are exported as pdf files and included in the Latex document.

I want a box around the graphics included that containd the number of figure and the caption.

Comment: Have you tried to use the float environnement?

Comment: You could take a look at the `tcolorbox` or `mdframed` packages, combined with the  `caption` package.

Comment: @Bernard, That's funny :p , I'm already looking on the tcolorbox package now, thanks

Comment: I have edited my post by putting my essay, can you help please?

Comment: Maybe you can use nested tables and multicolums.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this solution using `tcolorbox` ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{myfigure}[2][]{enhanced,center upper,
  colback=white,colbacktitle=black!20!white,coltitle=black,
  arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,fonttitle=\scshape,lefttitle=2.4cm,
  boxrule=0.3mm,
  overlay={
    \fill[black!20!white] ([xshift=2.2cm,yshift=-0.3mm]title.south west) rectangle (frame.north east);
    \fill[black] ([yshift=-0.3mm]title.south west) rectangle
      node[white] {\sffamily Figure~\thetcbcounter}
      ([xshift=2.2cm]title.north west);
  },title={#2},#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{myfigure}{Prevalence des Prescriptions des Molecules d'Antibiotiques
  les plus Frequntes, par Annee d'Enquete}
\includegraphics[width=10cm]{example-image-a}
\end{myfigure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If this new figure should contain the chapter number and behave like an 'ordinary' LaTeX figure, use the following modification:

```
\newtcolorbox[use counter=figure,number within=chapter,
  list inside=lof,list type=figure]{myfigure}[2][]{enhanced,center upper,
  colback=white,colbacktitle=black!20!white,coltitle=black,
  arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,fonttitle=\scshape,lefttitle=2.4cm,
  boxrule=0.3mm,
  overlay={
    \fill[black!20!white] ([xshift=2.2cm,yshift=-0.3mm]title.south west) rectangle (frame.north east);
    \fill[black] ([yshift=-0.3mm]title.south west) rectangle
      node[white] {\sffamily Figure~\thetcbcounter}
      ([xshift=2.2cm]title.north west);
  },title={#2},#1}
```

Then, the new figure will be listed inside the list of figures using

```
\listoffigures
```

Comment: Thak you for your help, this is what I expected, but I got an error when compiling: Unknown option `many` for package `tcolorbox`. \ProcessOptions*

Comment: I will try to update packages and tell you

Comment: I quite sure that you have an old version of `tcolorbox`. The current version is `3.00`. After an update, it should work.

Comment: Worked perfectly ! I did not find words to thank you !

Comment: please how can I change the code in order to increment with the chapter; for example : figure 2.3 (it means the third figure in the second chapte)  I found this command `\refstepcounter` but I dont know how to use it. I also want the  box to be referenced in the table of figure with its name. thanks

Comment: I found the option for the the counter, I used `number within=chapter` option

Comment: @user42987 I'm glad that I could help. Maybe, it's also useful to know for you that you can make the figure floatable by adding the option `float` to the keylist or - more flexible - individually by using `\begin{myfigure}[float]{...`

Comment: I want all the new box to be listed in the list of figure. How can I do that?

Comment: @user42987 See my updated answer.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to accept an answer twice :)) , Your answer worked perfectly. I even change `lof` by `lot` to include the box in the list of table

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to draw the graph, I suggest you have a look at a drawing program using LaTeX or producing LaTeX-code.

One program is [Ipe v 7](http://ipe7.sourceforge.net/). Another program is Nicola Talbot’s [jpgfdraw](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/apps/jpgfdraw/index.html).

**Ipe** is using LaTeX to produced PDF-files you may include in the main document.

Comment: Thak you for your help,  I'm not looking for producing graphics, I Just want to produce a box (similar to the one above) around my included plots that contain the number of the figure and the caption.

Comment: @user42987 Then just put the picture in an ‘fbox’.

Comment: @user42987 You may also try ‘framebox’, http://www.forkosh.com/latex/ltx-237.html