# Memoir boxed example environment

Tags: environments, memoir

Memoir's manual has this example of *frame with title* environment. I was wondering how can I add a counter to it? Say, to mimic the AMS theorem environments. Any better way of achieving this in memoir is also welcomed.

```
 \documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright,a4paper]{memoir}
 \newcommand{\FrameTitle}[2]{%
 \fboxrule=\FrameRule \fboxsep=\FrameSep
 \fbox{\vbox{\nobreak \vskip -0.7\FrameSep
 \rlap{\strut#1}\nobreak\nointerlineskip% left justified
 \vskip 0.7\FrameSep
 \hbox{#2}}}}
 \newenvironment{framewithtitle}[2][\FrameFirst@Lab\ (cont.)]{%
 \def\FrameFirst@Lab{\textbf{#2}}%
 \def\FrameCont@Lab{\textbf{#1}}%
 \def\FrameCommand##1{%
 \FrameTitle{\FrameFirst@Lab}{##1}}%
 \def\FirstFrameCommand##1{%
 \FrameTitle{\FrameFirst@Lab}{##1}}%
 \def\MidFrameCommand##1{%
 \FrameTitle{\FrameCont@Lab}{##1}}%
 \def\LastFrameCommand##1{%
 \FrameTitle{\FrameCont@Lab}{##1}}%
\MakeFramed{\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}}%
{\endMakeFramed}
\begin{document}
\begin{framewithtitle}{Test} This is a test.
\end{framewithtitle}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Can you turn this into a compilable example rather than a code fragment?  It would be much easier for people to play with your code.

Comment: @AlanMunn: Done.

Comment: For a solution, perhaps the `mdframed` package would be helpful.  It's designed to do this sort of thing out of the box (no pun intended).  See e.g. [TikZ -The pretty boxes to frame the theorems-lemma-proposition-etc](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122848) (and I'm sure there are other examples on the site.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use either the [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) or the [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) packages; both offer you an easy key-value interface to define decorated theorem-like structures that will automatically include numeration (and easy control over the counter used).

In the following example code I show a comparison between the environment that **Herbert** provided in [`his answer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/195501/3954) with five other environments built using the packages mentioned above. Using those packages you can easily produce as elaborate decorations as you wish (in my example I restricted to somehow "sober" structures, but you can easily experiment with different styles):

[image]

The code:

```
 \documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright,a4paper]{memoir}
 \usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
 \usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
 \usepackage{amsthm}


 \newtcbtheorem[number within=chapter]{testiv}{Test}{   
   outer arc=0pt,arc=0pt}{tha}
 \newtcbtheorem[number within=chapter]{testv}{Test}{   
   outer arc=0pt,
   arc=0pt,
   colback=white,
   colframe=black,
   colbacktitle=white,
   titlerule=0pt,
   fonttitle=\normalcolor\itshape}{thb}

 \newmdtheoremenv{testi}{Test}[chapter]
 \newmdtheoremenv[
   backgroundcolor=gray!50
 ]{testii}{Test}[chapter]
 \theoremstyle{remark}
 \newmdtheoremenv{testiii}{Test}[chapter]

 \newcounter{FrameCnt} \setcounter{FrameCnt}{0}
 \newcommand{\FrameTitle}[2]{%
   \fboxrule=\FrameRule \fboxsep=\FrameSep
   \fbox{\vbox{\nobreak \vskip -0.7\FrameSep
   \rlap{\strut#1}\nobreak\nointerlineskip% left justified
   \vskip 0.7\FrameSep
   \hbox{#2}}}}
 \newenvironment{framewithtitle}[2][\FrameFirst@Lab\ (cont.)]
   {\refstepcounter{FrameCnt}%
    \def\FrameFirst@Lab{\textbf{#2~\theFrameCnt}}%
    \def\FrameCont@Lab{\textbf{#1}}%
    \def\FrameCommand##1{\FrameTitle{\FrameFirst@Lab}{##1}}%
    \def\FirstFrameCommand##1{\FrameTitle{\FrameFirst@Lab}{##1}}%
    \def\MidFrameCommand##1{\FrameTitle{\FrameCont@Lab}{##1}}%
    \def\LastFrameCommand##1{\FrameTitle{\FrameCont@Lab}{##1}}%
    \MakeFramed{\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}}
  {\endMakeFramed}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test chapter}

Using your environmet:
\begin{framewithtitle}{Test} 
This is a test.
\end{framewithtitle}

\noindent Using \texttt{mdframed}:
\begin{testi}
This is a test.
\end{testi}

\begin{testii}
This is a test.
\end{testii}

\begin{testiii}
This is a test.
\end{testiii}

\noindent Using \texttt{tcolrbox}:
\begin{testiv}{}{}
This is a test.
\end{testiv}

\begin{testv}{}{}
This is a test.
\end{testv}

\end{document}
```

As **Alan** has mentioned in [`his comment`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195499/memoir-boxed-example-environment#comment452391_195499), more colorful options can be found in the answers to [TikZ -The pretty boxes to frame the theorems-lemma-proposition-etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122848/3954) and i many other answers in this site.

Comment: Why is there such an uneven vertical spacing in the `mdframed` examples?

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright,a4paper]{memoir}
 \newcounter{FrameCnt} \setcounter{FrameCnt}{0}
 \newcommand{\FrameTitle}[2]{%
   \fboxrule=\FrameRule \fboxsep=\FrameSep
   \fbox{\vbox{\nobreak \vskip -0.7\FrameSep
   \rlap{\strut#1}\nobreak\nointerlineskip% left justified
   \vskip 0.7\FrameSep
   \hbox{#2}}}}
 \newenvironment{framewithtitle}[2][\FrameFirst@Lab\ (cont.)]
   {\refstepcounter{FrameCnt}%
    \def\FrameFirst@Lab{\textbf{#2~\theFrameCnt}}%
    \def\FrameCont@Lab{\textbf{#1}}%
    \def\FrameCommand##1{\FrameTitle{\FrameFirst@Lab}{##1}}%
    \def\FirstFrameCommand##1{\FrameTitle{\FrameFirst@Lab}{##1}}%
    \def\MidFrameCommand##1{\FrameTitle{\FrameCont@Lab}{##1}}%
    \def\LastFrameCommand##1{\FrameTitle{\FrameCont@Lab}{##1}}%
    \MakeFramed{\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}}
  {\endMakeFramed}
\begin{document}
\begin{framewithtitle}{Test\label{foo}} This is a test.
\end{framewithtitle}

As seen in Frame \ref{foo} \ldots
\end{document}
```

[image]